Upper bound for supremum of Lipschitz function
Given a Lipschitz function $L$, I want to show the following: For $\gamma >0$, let $\chi(\gamma)$ be an equidistant partition on $[0,1]$ with grid length $n^{-\gamma}$ where $n \ge 1$. Then
\begin{align*}
\sup_{t \in [0,1]} |L(t)-\mathbb{E}L(t)|
&\le 
\sup_{s \in \chi(\gamma)} |L(s)-\mathbb{E}L(s)|\\
&+
\sup_{s,t \in [0,1], |t-s| \le n^{-\gamma}} |L(t)-L(s)|
+
\sup_{s,t \in [0,1], |t-s| \le n^{-\gamma}} |\mathbb{E}L(t)-\mathbb{E}L(s)|.
\end{align*}
My attempt is:
\begin{align*}
\sup_{t \in [0,1]} |L(t)-\mathbb{E}L(t)|
&\le 
\sup_{s \in \chi(\gamma), t \in [0,1]} 
|L(t) - L(s) + L(s) - \mathbb{E}L(s) + \mathbb{E}L(s)-\mathbb{E}L(t)|\\
&\le 
\sup_{s \in \chi(\gamma)} 
|L(s) - \mathbb{E}L(s)|
+
\sup_{s \in \chi(\gamma), t \in [0,1]} |L(t) - L(s)|
+
\sup_{s \in \chi(\gamma), t \in [0,1]} |\mathbb{E}L(s)-\mathbb{E}L(t)|
\end{align*}
I am confused as to why the second and third terms can be bounded above by the supremum over the region $|t-s| \le n^{-\gamma}$.
This is the first part of the proof of Lemma 5 on page 36 of this article.
Update: I think the notation threw me off a little, I think what is going on is:
\begin{align*}
\sup_{t \in [0,1]} |L(t)-\mathbb{E}L(t)|
&\le 
\sup_{t \in [0,1]} \sup_{s \in \chi(t; \gamma)}
|L(t) - L(s) + L(s) - \mathbb{E}L(s) + \mathbb{E}L(s)-\mathbb{E}L(t)|
\end{align*}
where $\chi(t; \gamma)$ is poor notation but it is just the nearest point in the partition to $t$.
